# $D$ is a disk. Show that we cannot find congruent sets $A$, $B$ with $A \cap B = \emptyset$, $ A \cup B = D$

Tags: geometry

$D$ is a disk. Show that we cannot find congruent sets $A$, $B$ with $A \cap B = \emptyset$, $ A \cup B = D$.

----------I considered the Curve and that the area of disc in partitioned in half. Then the curve between points on edge of disc call it curve $C$ can be partitioned as well as it is points to either A or B (set) but then the KIcker !!:  it leaves one point left after u partition this disc twice and guess where that would be ? :) look below for answer------->>>>>>>>>

Comment: Please, consider including your work in the question.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Comment: Ross Honsberger discusses this problem in one of his *Mathematical Gems* books.

Comment: which one ? i will order it online asap

Comment: I never read honsberger gems but will definitly order them ! being a Mathematezoid that would be a new dosage lol  seriously though I believe my proof is correct and orginal.

Comment: you can always find two points 'diamterically opposite' on the closed disc (of any r) . that means also a curve that passes through these two points also passes though center. Then because the union of all points on D  can be can be partitioned into both sets A and B , and the closed Curve by Jordan's Theorem (whoopty hoop :)) can also be partitoned (continuity) into these two sets A and B all the way down to the last point ,.,, the center which means one of these sets will have this point and thus contradicts congruence of sets A and B

Answer (score 3):

So assume $A,B$ are congruent by a motion $T$, say $T(A)=B$.

Can $f$ be a translation? Consider the diameter $pq$ of $D$ orthogonal to the direction of translation. If $p\in A$, then $T(p)\in B$ is outside $D$. If $p\in B$ then $T^{-1}(p)\in A$ is outside $D$.

The same argument applies if $T$ is a glide reflection.

Can $T$ be a reflection? Any point on the axis is invariant under $T$ hence is either in $A\cap B$ or $(A\cup B)^c$. Since the former is empty and $A\cup B=D$, the axis must not intersect $D$. But then for any $P\in A$, $T(p)\in B$ is in the half plane not containing $D$.

Can $T$ be a rotation? As before, the centre $o$ of the rotation must be outside $D$. Consider the  diameter $pq$ of $D$ passing through $o$ (when prolonged). Then $T(p)$ and $T^{-1}(p)$ are $\notin D$, similar to the case of a translation.

Comment: sets A and B can fight over the center but cant share ---> hence contradiction they are both congruent ----><------

Comment: Actually my simpler proof was right ! What I thought was " higher math " ,wasn't all that high . a " glide reflection " in the answer below doesn't merit any points since it isn't defined and that would be needed in proving this type of problem . because the sets are discs , they are circles ,and the center of these discs is the kicker :)